# .net compact framework: Avoid program being started twice concurrently

Tags: compact-framework

How can I avoid that a user starts the same program twice?
The current implementation tries to do that using "FindWindow", but since it takes some time before the program opens the first window, users regulary manage to start the program  twice, causing errors etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use a named mutex so it can be used across processes.  For whatever (stupid) reason, the CF designers figured CF developers would never need such a thing, so you have 2 options:

1. P/Invoke CreateMutex and the associated clean up stuff
2. Use an already written implementation like the SDF's [NamedMutex class](http://opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/0bd35291-a154-0277-1dcf-233208d75a5f.htm) (which simply does #1 for you) from OpenNETCF.

There is actually a 3rd option as well.  The SDF's [Application2 class](http://opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/fcac3a8d-fb5b-fc77-74f4-5603c51c19bb.htm) has a couple [Run method overloads](http://opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/98173725-375a-b394-89dc-7affb44961cf.htm) that wraps this logic for you and enforces app singleton behavior.

Comment: Found a good description including samples here:

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/CreateMutex.html

Comment: this is absolutely astounding that CF has no named mutexes.  What a mistake.

Comment: Well there's pretty long list of things that they omitted that I consider WTFs.  Named mutexes isn't even in my top 20.

Answer (score 2):

Use this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/bb943002.aspx

Many of the alternatives out there are either too complicated or don't work all of the time.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it's too late for me... not working with .net anymore.

Comment: If you look at the waybackmachine, the article is there and the c# project is still there. http://web.archive.org/web/20120615205228/http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/0/0/f0048787-627a-4d39-b40f-e996c70ab0eb/CS-AppOneCopy_cs.zip